# Using the same view on both tabs in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-tabs

I'm working on an `Android` application with an activity that uses a tab layout. There are two tabs which switch between the content being shown in a `ListView` below.

This means that the two tab specifications point to the same `ListView` for content, `R.id.main_list`:

```
<TabWidget 
     android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<FrameLayout 
     android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <ListView 
          android:id="@+id/main_list" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
 </FrameLayout>
```

This somewhat works - if I switch to tab *#2* and back to *#1*, I can see the `ListView` and my database code gets the right data based on the selected tab. However, when the activity launches, the `ListView` can't be seen before tabs are changed. This is obviously a problem.

What's the least hacky way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two `ListView` widgets.